# OSX custom authorization plugin breaks with upgrade to Mojave

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, authorization, macos-mojave

We have a custom authorization plugin for OSX, written using this as our base:

https://github.com/skycocker/NameAndPassword

and referencing the official documentation where needed:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/authorization_plug-ins/using_authorization_plug-ins

The plugin was working perfectly, until the Mojave release. With Mojave, our auth plugin UI does not draw and we only see the circular login arrow button. The only way to login is to ssh into the machine, uninstall our auth plugin and re-enable to default OSX login mechanism.

We added additional logging and found that the plugin is indeed being loaded and runs normally. It's just the UI that is not displaying anymore. My guess is that they have changed some requirements for custom auth plugins but have not updated the documentation.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the UI might not be displaying in Mojave?

EDIT:
Some more information. We have found that we are able to tab through the controls that are part of our plugin. This implies that the controls are actually there, but are either off screen or maybe just not being drawn? Very strange indeed...

EDIT 2:
I tried building the NameAndPassword sample, and it displays fine in Mojave. This sample used a .nib for the interface, which I cannot edit in the recent version of xcode. So, I tried recreating the interface as a .xib and surprisingly, the UI for NameAndPassword is now gone as well!

So, there is perhaps something happening behind the scenes when the .xib file is compiled which is causing the UI to not be drawn, which is NOT happening with a .nib based interface.

Comment: Works fine for me on Mojave. I have a custom button in the login view and it displays and catches on click event fine. I have tried it on a VM but wouldn't think there would be a difference in behavior on a real hardware.

Comment: BTW, I tested on a clean installation of Mojave and not an upgrade from an earlier version of macOS.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution? I am experiencing the exact same problem, observing the same things you mention in EDIT and EDIT2.

Comment: We did find a solution, though not an explanation. All I did was resize the window so that it was smaller, and suddenly everything showed up. I have not figured out or read about any size restrictions, but in any case, that's what made it work for us.

Comment: @ChrisGiles thanks! I did some testing based on your findings and discovered that the width of my `designable.nib` needed to be less than roughly 395 to render correctly. Otherwise, it wold not display. I found no restrictions on the window's height.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have this flag enabled : self.window?.canBecomeVisibleWithoutLogin = true

Comment: Please do not post additional questions as an answer but rather as a comment.